# Есть ли протоколы межсерверной связи трафик которых трудно отснифать?

Tags: c#

Нужно приложению подключаться к серверу,ну и хотелось бы чтоб через обычные сниферы трафика не смотрели данные которые передаются.
Есть ли способы чтоб трафик не отображался в снифферах?

Comment: *Есть ли способы чтоб трафик не отображался в снифферах?* Нет. В принципе не существует. *чтоб через обычные сниферы трафика не смотрели данные которые передаются.* Какая связь-то? Любое шифрование - а там вроде и видишь, да хрен поймёшь.

Comment: Конкретики мало, вам подойдет пакетная инкапсуляция сетевого протокола на основе  IPsec

Comment: Нужно определиться с помощью чего соединяться с сервером для обмена данными. Ну данные будут шифроваться, интересно было  вот некоторые ПО в фидлере и чарльзе трафик не виден, что они используют.

Comment: Фидлер (и на сколько знаю чарльз) - это только HTTP трафик, включайте сокеты и вы вряд-ли их там увидите, но зато увидите через тот же браузер (F12) или софт, который ловит все виды пакетов. В наше время что угодно можно перехватить, хоть банковские запросы и тут главная задача сделать так, чтоб даже если у взломщика были данные на руках, то он не смог бы их прочитать.

Comment: Какую проблему вы хотите решить? Чтобы юзер не смог вмешиваться в обмен данными, или злоумышленник с другого компа не смог увидеть содержимое пакетов? Что качается первого, используйте контрольные суммы. Что касается второго, не изобретайте велосипеды, TLS прекрасно защищает трафик. Скрыть трафик полностью технически невозможно, ну только если перестать его передавать.

Comment: Хочу чтоб в фидлере и тп перехватчиках не отображался канал, те школьники не ддосили  мой сервак.

Comment: Скрыть хост и порт, куда улетают пакеты, невозможно.